# Ubuntu router with 2 NICs, traffic stops and I don't understand why

Tags: router, routing, nic

I'm currently running a Beaglebone black with bone-ubuntu-14.04-console-armhf-2014-08-13-2gb.img (or a more recent version), which acts as a firewall / router. It has two network interface, one USB adapter and one that is directly on the Beaglebone. At the moment I have no firewall on it.

Here is a picture of my network. I cannot modify the infrastructure.
http://snag.gy/zj7ri.jpg

From the beaglebone, I can ping up to TORONTO Ge0/1 (10.10.10.83) - not beyond.
On the other hand, the Toronto router can ping 192.168.43.6 (USB NIC on the Beaglebone) but it cannot ping 192.168.11.1 (which is the Eth interface on the beaglebone, basically the other side).

Also, from PC - Web server I can ping the USB NIC (wan) (192.168.43.6/30) on the Beaglebone, but I cannot ping the g0/0 interface on the Toronto router (192.168.43.5/30)

My goal is to ping the PC at the 10.10.10.10 address, and from the Toronto router, ping the 192.168.11.1 (eth0) interface on the beaglebone.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces configuration:

```
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo eth0
    iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.11.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.11.0
        gateway 192.168.43.6


# The WAN(internet) network interface

auto wan0
iface wan0 inet static
        address 192.168.43.6
        netmask 255.255.255.252
        network 192.68.43.4
        gateway 192.168.43.5

up route add -net 192.168.11.0/24 gw 192.168.11.1 dev eth0
up route add -net 192.168.43.4/30 gw 192.168.43.6 dev wan0
```

I also have /etc/sysctl.conf as:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The problem is that my Ubuntu cannot ping past my Ge0/1 interface on router.
And that my router cannot ping the LAN interface on the Ubuntu. It can however ping the WAN interface, which is a USB nic.

I can only use console.

Comment: 1. Can you put output of traceroute from TORONTO to 192.168.11.1 2. Put output from PC of traceroute to 192.168.11.1  3.Can you change config on TORONTO?